# How to retrieve Farm Metadata and Farm Topology Metadata's Objects and their properties

Tags: managed-metadata, sharepoint-farm

I want to retrieve Farm Metadata properties like ServersInTheFarm, WebApplications, SiteCollection and Content Database. In the Same way I want Farm Topology Metadata properties. How Can I retrieve this properties value using code?

And also I want different topology's property like SiteTopologyMetadata, SearchTopologyMetadata, ServicesOnServerMetadat. How can I retrieve property for this metadata.